# Interface with Generic method

Tags: java, generics, public

I have a bunch of different processors and every processor has its own `ProcessorRequest` and `ProcessorResponse` classes.

```
public class Processor1 {
    ProcessorResponse1 process(ProcessorRequest1 request) {
        // do something
    }
}


public class Processor2 {
    ProcessorResponse2 process(ProcessorRequest2 request) {
        // do something
    }
}

public class Processor3 {
    ProcessorResponse3 process(ProcessorRequest3 request) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

All `ProcessorRequest` classes extend the `BaseRequest` class, and all `ProcessorResponse` classes extend the `BaseResponse` class.

Now, I have requirement to make all `Processor` classes implement a common interface `BaseProcessor` so, that if possible do not touch existing code:

```
public interface BaseProcessor {

    public RRR process(TTT request) throws Exception;

}
```

Where `RRR` and `TTT` are corresponding `ProcessorResponse` and `ProcessorRequest`.

I tried to do it with Generics.

```
public interface Baserocessor<T extends BaseRequest, R extends BaseResponse> {

    public R process(T request) throws Exception;

}
```

But in this case, I need to change the signature of every process method and cast `BaseRequest` to a `ProcessorRequest`:

```
public class Processor1 {
    BaseResponse process(BaserRequest baseRequest) {
        ProcessorRequest1 request = (ProcessorRequest1) baseRequest;
        // do something
    }
}
```

Is there another way to do it without changes in every single processor?

Comment: If you declare `class Processor1 extends Baserocessor<ProcessorRequest1, ProcessorResponse1>`, you don't need any explicit casts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You processor classes should implement the generic interface as follows:

```
public class Processor1 implements BaseProcessor<ProcessorRequest1, ProcessorResponse1> {
    ProcessorResponse1 process(ProcessorRequest1 request) {
        // do something
    }
}
```